# Which type of classification best suits this scatter plot?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance

The following image shows a scatter plot of my data. The Y axis points are the labels, labeled from 1 to 6 and X-axis are dimensionally reduced values of all my features. I reduced them for better visualization. 
[image]

I have used decision Trees and Random forests both give a score of 0.74 and 0.79 respectively.

I have also tried SVM and Naive Bayes just for seeing the score they gave 0.37 and 0.33 respectively.

I was using 75% to train and the rest to test.

Which is the best classification algorithm for this data? Multiclass Classification

Comment: Can you provide more information on the dimensionality of your dataset? Too much information is lost if you try to distill it down to one single feature. Perhaps you can utilise some multivariate graphs like andrews plot or parallel coordinates to provide more information? As a start, you can try k-Nearest Neighbours? That's commonly used and easy to handle algorithm. PS: I would like to have commented instead of writing an answer first..but unfortunately I don't have enough rep for now. Put up more information and I'll see what I can add to this answer?